# Add host on Cloudstack with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I have successfully installed cloud stack management server on Ubuntu 12.04 with vmware , now I need to know how can I add a Host ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hypervisor you're using, the instructions on how to add the host to CloudStack will differ slightly. Instructions for Xen, KVM, and VMWare/VSphere are in the docs at http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/latest/configuration.html#adding-a-host

Comment: i have successfully configure cloudstack 4.4.2 in a single node, now i want to add a service of video conference ,so how can i do it ? .
i ' m a beginner in cloud computing appreciate your help , thank you .

Comment: You need to create a VM in CloudStack. Once that VM is running, login and install/run whatever video conferencing software you wish.